# How to pass file pointer in dll routines using ctypes in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dll, ctypes

I'm accessing one function from dll which need file pointer (char *filename).  How can I pass it through python?

```
handle = cdll.dsp

p = open("signal.txt", "r")

handle.filter(p)
```

Comment: A "file pointer" is `FILE*`, whereas `char*` is a string.

Comment: Hi, Abrams,
So according to you what is the meaning of char* filename
If I'm wrong, please let me know

Comment: Uh... it sounds like a string containing a filename to me...

Answer (score 0):

A file pointer is `FILE *`. But you mentioned you need `char *filename`, which is a char pointer (i.e. a null-terminated string). I'm going to assume the C function has a prototype `void filter(char *filename)`.

First you must [define the function argument types and the return type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#specifying-the-required-argument-types-function-prototypes):

```
import ctypes
filter = ctypes.cdll.dsp.filter
filter.argtypes = (ctypes.c_char_p,)
filter.restype = None  # Or whatever type it returns.
```

Then you call it:

```
filter(b"signal.txt")
```

By the way, you tagged your question as Python 2.7, but nowadays you should move on to Python 3, unless you have a really good reason to stay at the older version.

Comment: don't you have to add "b" before your string "signal.txt" in order to get bytes = b'...' literals = a sequence of octets (integers between 0 and 255) !

Comment: Yes, you're right. The plain syntax `"foobar"` is ambiguous, as it means a byte-string in Python 2 and a unicode-string in Python 3. It's better to use `b"foobar"` for byte-strings, as that's compatible with both versions. (And `from __future__ import unicode_literals` if you still need compatibility with Python 2 for whatever reason.) Thanks for pointing out, I'm updating my answer.